# file_get_contents gets different file from google than shown in browser

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

I use file_get_contents to find out if there is an URL of the search I look at:

`http://www.google.com/search?q=*a*+site:www.reddit.com/r/+-inurl:(/shirt/|/related/|/domain/|/new/|/top/|/controversial/|/widget/|/buttons/|/about/|/duplicates/|dest=|/i18n)&num=1&sort=date-sdate`

If I go to this URL in my browser, a different file is displayed then what I see when I echo `file_get_contents`

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=*a*+site:www.reddit.com/r/+-inurl:(/shirt/|/related/|/domain/|/new/|/top/|/controversial/|/widget/|/buttons/|/about/|/duplicates/|dest=|/i18n)&num=1&sort=date-sdate";
$google_search = file_get_contents($url);
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing really. The problem is that the page uses javascript and ajax to get contents. So, in order to get a "snapshot" of the page, you need to "run it". That is, you need to parse the javascript code, which php doesn't do.

Your best bet is to use an headless browser such as phantomjs. If you search, you find some tutorials explaining how to do it

**NOTE**

If all you're looking for is a way to retrieve raw data from the search, you might want to try to use [google's search api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/).

Answer (score 1):

I assume Google is definitely checking the user agent to avoid any kind of automated searches.

So you should at least use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and define a proper user agent string (i.e. the same as a common browser) to "trick" Google.

Somehow I fear it will not be so easy to trick Google, but maybe I'm just paranoic and at least you may learn something about CURL.